# How do I programmatically change layout in ASP,NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently working on multi theme base solution using ASP.NET 5, and looking for a way to change master view name programmatically. In classic ASP.NET MVC application, I can achieve this by modifying ViewResult's `MasterName` property, however it doesn't exist in ASP.NET 5 anymore.

```
protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
        {
            // set master for theming

            (filterContext.Result as ViewResult).MasterName = <get layout from db> service
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you mean the layout, e.g. _Layout.cshtml? You can set `this.Layout` property of/in your view via a code block.

Comment: @ˈvɔlə Is layout same as Master Name in classic ASP.NET MVC ? I haven't looked into details. I don't want to change to razor view dynamically, instead I want to set layout path before the view rendered dynamically.

Comment: Perhaps share the code you have tried and clearly describe the one challenge you would like assistance with in your question.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I've added my classic ASP.NET Mvc implementation source code in the original post, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can change the layout file programmatically in an ASP.NET Core controller action:

**Using Page:**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout1-2-3.cshtml";
}
...
```

**Using ViewStart Page:**

```
@{  
   
    dynamic Layout;  
    switch (case)  
    {  
        case "1":  
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout-1.cshtml";  
            break;  
        default:   
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";  
            break;  
    }  
}
```

**Using Action:**

```
public IActionResult Action()
{
    ViewData["Layout"] = "~/Views/Shared/Layout1-2-3.cshtml";

    return View();
}
```

Comment: #1 and #2 are not what I want. The layout is stored in database and retrieved via a service. #3 seems simpler and similar to what I want, however it doesn't work. I tested with ASP.NET Core Web App (Model -View-Controller) , layout didn't get changed. Have you tested it?

Comment: Using #3 requires using #1 or #2. You can check the [gist](https://gist.github.com/emreakdemir/7010da65096ee70df2f32a8dd8a59d10). I have tested it and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I now understand your suggested approach. Frankly speaking, I'm not big fan of this approach using ViewData or ViewBag either way. The classic ASP.NET MVC has a property MasterName  on ViewResult which seems neater than this. I'm looking for equivalent thingy in ASP.NET Core or .NET 5

Comment: I understand, I haven't seen such usage before. Detailed information is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0). But if you want, you can create your own ViewResult by extending ViewResult. Alternatively, you can definitely return a ViewModel for each action. You can also change the layout from a single location using this ViewModel with _ViewImports.cs. Have good work.